# How to get a list of paths in /etc/ld.so.conf on Linux

Tags: linux, lua, shared-libraries, debian, ldd

What is the most portable and robust way to get the list of paths, configured by `/etc/ld.so.conf` and files included from it? Parsing the file manually seems to be not a good idea — the format is likely to change in the future revisions.

---

*To allow better understanding of the question, I will give you specific details below. Note that, despite these details, this is a general programming question, applicable to other situations.*

There is a program, called [LuaRocks](http://luarocks.org). It is a package manager for Lua programming language (somewhat like Ruby gems or Python eggs). LuaRocks packages are called "rocks".

As a convenience feature, LuaRocks allows a rock author to specify a list of external dependencies for a rock, formulated as a list of C header files and / or dynamic library files. (.so on Linux.) If the specified file does not exist, the rock can't be installed.

Currently, on Linux, LuaRocks by default checks .so file existance by searching for the file in two <strike>hardcoded</strike> paths, `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`.

I believe that this is incorrect behaviour, and it is [broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52617/usr-lib-i386-linux-gnu/52619#52619) by the recent [changes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) in the Ubuntu and other Debian distributions.

*Update: the paths  are not hardcoded per se, but are user-configurable in the config file. Still, IMO, not a best solution.*

Instead (as I understand it), LuaRocks should look up file in the paths, specified by `/etc/ld.so.conf` and files included from it.

*(Now please re-read the question above ;-) )*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to parse /etc/ld.so.conf or any of the config files - if you run 'ldconfig', it will scan the configured directories and generate a cache file.

Then, subsequently when you attempt a dlopen it'll automatically find the files by iterating through the cached library directories. Same thing with compiling and giving -lSomeLib, you shouldn't need to specify -L/my/other/path if you've got it configured in ld.so.conf(.d)

autoconf accomplishes this by attempting to compile a test program that links to the shared library, but that's just a functional wrapper around the dlopen() call.

So, while other methods may not necessarily be 'wrong', at the root of it attempting to link to the library or doing a dlopen() are the 'most right' ways of doing it.

Consider this, if you attempt to link to a library in a directory that ISN'T cached in /etc/ld.so.cache, when you try to run the program it will fail because it won't be able to dlopen() the library!

Hence, any 'good' shared library will be in /etc/ld.so.cache and be linkable/dlopen()able, this means that gcc can use it to link and that the user-generated library or executable will be able to open it when it executes.

You can circumvent this by expressly setting the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or LD_PRELOAD_PATH - but each of these has it's own caveats and should be avoided if possible for 'standard' use.

A good write-up on writing shared libraries covers some of these issues, and is a good read for anyone working on programmatic consuming of other-shared libraries. [Ulrich Drepper's How to write shared libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Comment: The question is not related to dlopen: LR must decide if the system conforms to the contract of the rock before the rock (and the library) is installed.

Comment: Actually, it is since dlopen() is how the operating system finds dynamic libraries. The issues are intertwined. That is to say, if you run ldconfig, you don't need to 'search' for libraries - they'll be found automatically. But. Thanks for the down-vote anyway!

Comment: Well, it is related, OK, but the point is that LR must make a decision long before it would be able to call dlopen() or ldd on the file in question (the file may even not exist at this point — it is yet to be built).

Comment: You missed the point - you add directories to files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, then you run ldconfig, ldconfig generates /etc/ld.so.cache, then anything that is trying to find a shared library 'gcc foo.c -lMyLib', or 'ld -shared foo.c -lMyLib', or 'dlopen('MyLib')' reference the cache @ /etc/ld.so.cache, you don't need to specify the directories. This is specifically why when you install new shared libraries autoconf will emit a message saying 'You should rerun ldconfig to update your cache'. At that point you shouldn't have to provide any hints to make/compile tools.

Comment: Sorry, but no. The task is specifically to determine if given .so is available in the system. If it is not available, then computationally intensive installation process will not be launched. You're suggesting to drop this feature and hope that user does have the .so file in place. This decision is well outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: Again, you're missing the point. Nothing should look for a .so file in a specific directory, thats why dynamic library exists - otherwise _everything_ would go into one directory. If you can't dlopen the library, it's not configured in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*, and ostensibly not available on the system. In short, nothing should 'look at' /etc/ld.so.conf/*, anything that does is doing it the wrong way. This isn't an opinion, it's a fact. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: So, you're suggesting that to determine if .so is in the system, LR *must* call `dlopen()` on it, and *any* other way is wrong?

Comment: autoconf accomplishes this by attempting to compile a test program that links to the shared library, but that's just a functional wrapper around the dlopen() call. So, while other methods may not necessarily be 'wrong', at the root of it attempting to link to the library or doing a dlopen() are the 'most right' ways of doing it. Consider this, if you attempt to link to a library that ISN'T cached in /etc/ld.so.cache, when you try to run the program it will fail because it won't be able to dlopen() the library! Hence, any 'good' library will be in /etc/ld.so.cache and be linkable/dlopen()able.

Comment: OK, now I get that you mean, thanks. Please consider editing your answer for clarity. I remove the downvote then (so far it is locked)...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/), the following are valid locations for dynamic libraries:

```
/lib*/
/opt/*/lib*/
/usr/lib*/
/usr/local/lib*/
```

(And most likely `~/lib*/` as well.)

All entries in my `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` conform to this. Some entries reference subdirectories below the FHS dirs, which probably means that you can use the libraries in there without path information.

Now I don't know enough about LuaRocks. If you're limited to Lua-path-style globs (only `?`), you cannot match these and have to parse the configs. Otherwise, you could just try to find them anywhere in these directories.

This would break on non-FHS-conforming systems (only option: parse config) and if a directory is not included in the config, the installer might see libraries that the linker cannot find.

These two seem acceptable to me, therefore I'd simply ignore the config and look at these dirs.

(Another possibility could be trying to link the library, this should automagically use the right path.  However, this is platform-specific and maybe dangerous.)

Comment: Lua-path-style-globs are irrelevant here (and we're talking about code change in LR, so thats not a problem anyway).

Comment: Direct lookup in directories looks not robust enough — admin user may reconfigure the system differently anyway.

Comment: Linking the library (or invoking ldd on it) is not acceptable for performance and sanity reasons.

Comment: @Alexander, why not? It ought to be reasonably fast for an installer, unless you're looking for a few hundred solibs. Just `fork()`, call `dlopen()` from the forked process, and exit with an exit code indicating whether you succeeded.

Comment: @bdonlan: Sorry, "why not" — what of three?

Comment: Why not link the library to check for existence, I mean

Comment: @bdonlan: If by "link the library" you mean "invoke `dlopen`", then maybe, yes.

Comment: @nobody: Please quote the appropriate part of FHS where all those `*` are described. I fail to find them.

Comment: @Alexander: The alternate format lib directories are written as `lib<qual>` over there, you can find them from the ToC.  `<qual>` could be anything, therefore `*`.

Comment: @nobody: Can you please give me a quote that says that explicitly, I need to prove this fact to LR authors. As I said, I failed to find that.

Comment: @Alexander [/lib<qual>](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#LIBLTQUALGTALTERNATEFORMATESSENTIAL) (also see linked [footnote](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#FTN.AEN890): "...`/lib32` and `/lib64` *might* be the library directories" (emph. mine)), [/usr/lib<qual>](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLIBLTQUALGTALTERNATEFORMATLIBRARI), [/opt](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) "...must locate its static files in a separate /opt/<package> or /opt/<provider> directory tree" (having same structure as `/`).  like so?

Comment: @Alexander Ah, and [this, subsection "specific options"](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) says "If directories `/lib<qual>` or `/usr/lib<qual>` exist, the equivalent directories must also exist in `/usr/local`."

Comment: @nobody: how does that imply that `<qual>` may be a subdirectory as it is in Ubuntu / Debian?